# Mongoose Latitude & Longitude validation is not working while saving in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following is my schema for Location collection:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    street : {type: String, required: true},
    area : {type: String, required: true},
    city : {type: String, required: true},
    state : {type: String, required: true},
    zip : {type: String, required: true},
    country : {type: String, default: 'IN'},
    pointers:{type: [], index: '2dsphere'}
});
```

While saving data in mongo using mongoose pointers are store as string not as number. Got following response:

```
"street": "rani sati marg",
"area": "malad east",
"city": "mumbai",
"state": "maharashtra",
"zip": "400097",
"pointers": [
    "72.857452,19.857452"
],
"country": "IN"
```

I want pointer values in number like: [72.857452,19.857452]

Comment: You didn't actually ask for it. `"pointers": { "type": [Number], "index": "2dphere" }` actually states that the content in the array **must** be numeric, and will "autocast" as such when sent an array of "strings" like you have done.

Comment: then getting Cast to Array failed for value error while validating.

Answer (score 0):

Missed that the string contained the comma in the source data.

For that you still want a numeric "type" in the schema:

```js
"pointers": { "type": [Number], "index": "2dphere" }
```

But you **also** want a "setter" function to do the transformation for you:

```js
LocationSchema.path("pointers").set(function(value) {
    if ( typeof(value[0]) == "string" && value.length == 1 ) {
        return value[0].split(",");
    } else {
        return value;
    }
});
```

And that's it. The `Number` type within the array will work out the casting from "String" to numeric for you, so no need for `parseFloat` or anything like that since it's already handled.

All you really need in the "setter" is to work out that:

> "If the array I got contains a string and there is only **one** element, then I presume it's comma seperated and split that string into an array.

You might want to do some more stringent logic than that, but that is the basic method for implementing a transformation on the data passed to the "setter".

Gives me:

```js
pointers: [ 72.857452, 19.857452 ]
```

Just like it should.

Comment: using above solution got `Cast to Array failed for value \"72.857452,19.857452\"` this error

Comment: @AsheshKhatri No you didn't if you actually used the `.set()` as is shown in the answer. So if you are actually submitting data like `"pointers": [ "72.857452,19.857452"]` with a single string in an array like your question asks, then the function of the supplied "setter" will split that string into an array of two elements and set the value accordingly. In in fact you are just submitting `"pointers": "72.857452,19.857452"` then rather than looking at the `0` index of `value`, you instead just test and issue the `split()` directly on `value` i.e `return value.split(",")`.